# YouTube API and brand account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-signin, youtube-data-api

I am using, since a long time, a Google script that accesses my YouTube channel, gets and modifies some information from it and saves some data in a Google sheet.

It always worked fine, but then, about a week ago, Google somehow split my access rights between my normal account (primary email) and my YouTube account (that goes under a different nickname).

I cannot find a way to run even the simplest command:

```
var my_playlists = YouTube.Playlists.list('snippet', {
    mine: true,
    maxResults: 50,
})
.items;
```

The problem is that google now prompts me with an authorization page and I can choose between 2 accounts. One is my primary account, the other is the YouTube one. 
If I choose my primary account, the code runs but I cannot see the data of the YouTube account.

If I choose the YouTube one, I still cannot access the data I want and it keeps asking for permission every time I run the code.

I understand there is a problem of authorization between the two channels, but I did not have it before and cannot find any suggestion to solve it.

What can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Instead of `mine` have you tried a `channelId`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and few other options, using both the code of the script and directly within the google API interface, but could not solve it

Comment: Could you post the related code snippets for your sign-in? I'm thinking there might something new related to the scopes related to auth. Have you also tried using your YouTube account to generate the data?

Comment: The relevant part of code is what I posted in my question. A request to YouTube API v3 to return the list of channels I am subscribed to.  
This is the code of a simplified full script:  
`function myFunction() {
var my_playlists = YouTube.Playlists.list('snippet',
mine:true, 
maxResults:50}).items;
Logger.log(my_playlists)}`

Scripts have to be authorized. That happens with a google sign in window, the first time you run the code. Now, running the code I have to choose which account to authorize (primary or youtube), but both fail to return those data.

Comment: Still no reply here :(

Answer (score 2):

I've been struggling with the exact same issue but for another cause.
Anyways, so far I can manipulate anything I want within my PERSONAL youtube account, granting access using OAuth to MY ACCOUNT, but if grant access to my branded account, the script doesn't even begin, apparently it's a bug that causes loop in the script.

You can check this out for more info:

- [YouTube Apps Script API only runnable by accounts without a YouTube channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520366/youtube-apps-script-api-only-runnable-by-accounts-without-a-youtube-channel)
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764531
- https://mashe.hawksey.info/2017/09/identity-crisis-using-the-youtube-api-with-google-apps-script-and-scheduling-live-broadcasts-from-google-sheets/
- [Using Youtube Data API to Edit with Brand Account Playlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50283549/using-youtube-data-api-to-edit-with-brand-account-playlist)

Comment: have you found ny solution to that? having same problem.