# Add videos to watch later on brand account using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube, scripting, google-signin, youtube-data-api

I am attempting to use the [script created by DiRaven from the reddit YouTube forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/youtube/comments/2x3ew4/automatically_add_new_subscription_videos_to_the/) that searches your email for YouTube video alerts and automatically adds those videos to the Watch Later playlist. I was able to get the script to work, but not in the correct location. Instead of the script directing the videos to my brand account's watch later playlist, it moves them to my private account's watch later playlist. Despite me allowing the script permission on my brand account when prompted, it does not seem to care that I have added it, and will only work when I give permission to the private account, which seems to operate as the parent account for any YouTube channel you create afterwards. I was wondering was there any way to edit the script to use the YouTube channel ID to direct the videos to the correct WL playlist. Besides this issue, the script works flawlessly. Pasted below just in case it is needed. Thanks.

EDIT: This post describes the same issue I am trying to describe in case what I am saying is not clear: [YouTube API and brand account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44472023/youtube-api-and-brand-account)

```
function AddMarkArchivedMailAsReadTrigger()
{
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('MarkArchivedMailAsRead')
  .timeBased()
  .everyHours(1)
 .create();
}

function MarkArchivedMailAsRead()
{
  var threads = GmailApp.search('has:nouserlabels -in:Sent -in:Chat -
in:Draft -in:Inbox is:unread');

  for (var thread in threads) threads[thread].markRead(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the brand account of interest to your default log in, when using the log in credentials. To do that, visit the youtube website, once logged in and the account of interest is selected, click the account icon in the top right corner of the screen. Choose settings. Choose Advanced to the right of the account avatar/icon. Scan the page for the option to set the account as the default account. Once that is done, that account will be the default account signed into and everything in your script should apply to that account.

The same steps can be followed afterwards to set any other account as default.