# YouTube Authentication

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube, google-oauth

I am trying to do two things using “Google Apps Script” with YouTube;

(a) Case I
 - Requirement  : For each of my Playlists, get Playlist details to a
   Google Sheet
 - Method   :  used code as below with **“PlaylistItems:
   list”** method  Added MY PLAYLIST ID using an array (Playlist IDs added
   manually to the Array).

```
 var cur_pl      = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list("snippet,contentDetails", {"maxResults": 50,"playlistId":MY PLAYLIST ID }) ;
    var modRes1 = cur_pl.items.map(function(v) {return [v.snippet.title,,v.snippet.position, v.etag];});
    Logger.log(modRes5);
```

- Result   : Worked as expected for all my “Public” playlists.

(b) Case II
 - Requirement  : Get a list of all of my Playlists to a Google Sheet
 - Method   :  used code as below using a similar concept to above (a) with **“Playlists: list”** Method.

```
var my_pl    = YouTube.Playlists.list("snippet,contentDetails",{"maxResults": 50,"mine": true })
var modRes2  = my_pl.items.map(function(v) {return [v.snippet.title,v.snippet.channelId]});
Logger.log(modRes2);
```

- Result        :  Not worked and throws this error

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.playlists.list failed
>   with error: Channel not found. (line 9, file ")

I tried both cases with “Try this API”  at following and worked as expected :
 - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list
 - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list

I think for the (case II), I may be missing authorization of my API request inside my Apps Script? Probably using API-Key or Auth2.0? 
(when I tried with “[Try this API][1]” I noted in code example they have  authorization steps.

**Question: How to add the Authorization (auth2 or API-Key) step into the script?**

Appreciate help

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. I cannot understand about `When I try the command using : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlists/list it work perfectly`. Can you explain about the detail of it? 2. Can you provide the detail of `when I try it on my App it doesn't work`? 3. I think that your script is for Javascript which is not Google Apps Script. Which do you want to achieve your goal usnig Javascript or Google Apps Script?

Comment: (1). When I fill the  ("Try this API") to retrieve my playlists using the link, I am getting all my results correctly in the response.  (2). but when I use the same parameters in the script : var cur_pl  = YouTube.Playlists.list ("snippet, contentDetails",{"maxResults":50,"mine": true}). It throws an error. (3) All I need is an Authentication step similar top that Java Script in my app. So your help appreciated (may be similar to authInfo.getAuthorizationStatus ?)

Comment: in another script when  I use : var cur_pl  = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list ("snippet,contentDetails",{"maxResults": 50,"pageToken": nextPgTk, "playlistId": <ID>}); to retrieve playlist items it works perfectly. so not sure why other code need an authentication?

Comment: Thank you for replying. About A1, I could understand. About A2, I cannot understand about `var cur_pl = YouTube.Playlists.list ("snippet, contentDetails",{"maxResults":50,"mine": true})`. I cannot understand about the relationship between this script  and the script in your question. About A3, I couldn't understand that what language do you want to use. In order to correctly understand about your question, how about updating your question by including the more information for your situation and your goal? I think that by this, it will help users think of the issue and solution.

Comment: "It throws a error" doesn't help anyone. Quote the error. Provide [mcve]

Comment: *may be missing authorization of my API request inside my Apps Script?* Meh... that's not it. Authorization is automatically taken care of. You're probably missing a parameter like channel id

Comment: Try `onBehalfOfContentOwner` instead of `mine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out be an issue due to the "YouTube API not Authorising a Google+ Page's YouTube Channel". This is a known issue and already discussed in below threads:

- [The YouTube API Will Not Authorize a Google+ Page's YouTube Channel](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36764531#comment2)
- [YouTube Apps Script API only runnable by accounts without a YouTube channel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520366/youtube-apps-script-api-only-runnable-by-accounts-without-a-youtube-channel)

So I revised my '(b) Case II - Requirement' above as below and it worked  :

```
var my_pl    = YouTube.Playlists.list("snippet,contentDetails",{"maxResults": 50, channelId: '**xxxxxxxxx**' })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apps Script as you said. There is no point to authenticate the way you are doing. I would even say that one of the points of Apps Script is to take all that "boring" stuff out of the way.

Just go ahead and enable the Youtube Service inside the Apps Script editor (**Resources > Advanced Google Services**).

[image]

After that you just can use any of the samples at **[App Script Youtube Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/youtube)**:

```js
/**
 * Searches for videos about dogs, then logs the video IDs and title.
 * Note that this sample limits the results to 25. To return more
 * results, pass additional parameters as shown in the YouTube Data API docs.
 * @see https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list
 */
function searchByKeyword() {
  var results = YouTube.Search.list('id,snippet', {
    q: 'dogs',
    maxResults: 25
  });

  results.items.forEach(function(item) {
    Logger.log('[%s] Title: %s', item.id.videoId, item.snippet.title);
  });
}
```

This is just an example and of course you can use any endpoint of the API and the scopes and authentication will be taken care of.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I did all you stated already and my scripts worked for 'Search', 'Channels', 'Playlistitems' etc but not for the "Playists.list" method. Even for the 'Playlistitems' it throws same error for "PRIVATE" playlists. but when I made them "PUBLIC" it worked perfectly. So is my reason to think some auth issue..