# What is correct way to get access to YouTube Data 3 API?

Tags: youtube-data-api

Dear YouTube Data 3 API support, it's a question for you.

With https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-ruby using json-key that we got to Service Account, we successfully get [TOKEN_KEY] for API calls.

But while we try to get Live Streaming list we get an error:

```
  {
    "message": "The user is not enabled for live streaming.",
    "domain": "youtube.liveBroadcast",
    "reason": "liveStreamingNotEnabled",
    "extendedHelp": "https://www.youtube.com/features"
  }
```

The request sample:

```
curl \
'https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatus&broadcastType=all&mine=true' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN_KEY]' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--compressed
```

What we have already done in Google Cloud Console:

- Create a Project
- Enable YouTube Dava 3 API
- Create an API key
- Create an OAuth ID
- Create an Service Account
- Connect Service Account in OAuth ID

We try some another ways but uselessly.

Of course, our account, in which we created the API application, has access for streaming through the studio.youtube.com (we have 10,000 subscribers and streams several times a week).

Also we studied the API documentation up and down, we do everything correctly step by step, as described.

**I can write a private email with my account information to YouTube Data 3 support member**, to make it easier for you to understand, and when we will successfully solve the problem I will write a comment to this question for the whole community.

Comment: Sorry, Maxim, but your question is misaddressed. SO is not *YouTube Data 3 API support*. YouTube Data API support is given by *Google* on its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: On the other hand, Maxim, please acknowledge that [YouTube APIs do not support service accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64388641/8327971). Third thing: you must enable live streaming within [YouTube Studio](https://studio.youtube.com): `Settings > Channel > Feature Eligibility` (your error above is pretty much self-explanatory).