# Upload videos with YouTube Data API on background in PHP

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to upload videos to YouTube using the YouTube Data API v3 in PHP in the background? I.e. without user interaction.

I've tried a few examples with OAuth2 and it always redirects me to a login page with a google account. Sometimes you even want to verify your identity via SMS.
I read the YouTube Data API documentation perhaps in its entirety.
The examples on developers.google.com only work with some redirects.

This is not usable for background video uploading.
Is it even possible?

Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application: _"This API supports two types of credentials. Create whichever credentials are appropriate for your project: [...]"_

Comment: This is the answer to your question: [How to get my own Google API access token without using "Log in with Google"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69149937/8327971)

Comment: You may also tailor to your needs this sample code from Google: [resumable_upload.php](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/resumable_upload.php).

Comment: RE: "This API supports two types of credentials. Create whichever credentials are appropriate for your project: [...]" : However, API keys for upload cannot be used. Upload requires user authentication.

Comment: All of the above examples require manual verification. The expiration time is one hour and then verified again. It is therefore not usable for automatic background synchronization.

Comment: @Jarda could you solve your problems?